# t-SNE for 2d points?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to visualize 2d embeddings of my deep learning model. Since my points are already 2d, can I directly plot them and see if there's any clustering or do I need to use something like t-SNE?

Comment: I wonder if the t-SNE will even do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of t-SNE is to reduce the dimension to something that can be visualized in two dimensions (maybe one or three), without sacrificing too much structure. Your data are in two dimensions, so the best way to reduce to two dimensions without sacrificing structure is to do nothing; just graph your scatterplot.

**EDIT**

To answer what I posted in a comment to the OP, the t-SNE indeed does something. (I divide by $10$ at the end to help the visualization, but that only affects the zoom, not the shape.)

```
library(Rtsne)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2021)
N <- 1000
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- rnorm(N)
tsne <- Rtsne::Rtsne(cbind(x, y))
d0 <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, Group = "Original")
d1 <- data.frame(x = tsne$Y[, 1]/10, y = tsne$Y[, 2]/10, Group = "t-SNE")
d <- rbind(d0, d1)
# plot(tsne$Y)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, col = Group)) +
geom_point() +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting that the t-SNE result looks like a clumpy mesh.

Comment: @Galen That's because it's evaluating only a few nearest neighbors of each point, which in effect is making the pattern look locally one-dimensional.  To recreate the overall pattern accurately, I believe the value of the `perplexity` argument should be made as large as possible.  Even then we should expect the output to be only some affine similarity of the original data, rather than an exact match.

Comment: To me, the t-SNE (in blue) looks like less of a "clump" than the original data.

Comment: @Dave I see what you mean. The original data looks more like a single "clump", which isn't the same as what I was going for with "clumpy mesh"; a limitation of imprecise language.

Comment: @Galen Try upping the sample size to $N <- 10000$ and plot the empirical probability integral transforms `ecdf(tsne$Y[, 1])(tsne$Y[, 1])` `ecdf(tsne$Y[, 2])(tsne$Y[, 2])`. The result looks wild! (The untransformed t-SNE plot is cool, too.)

Comment: @Dave Looks like an alien brain!